# Gallery 100% width on page

Tags: html, css, gallery

I cannot make my Gallery 100% width on my website

[image: Gallery]

This is my website, where you can see code in source the code http://pepi.g6.cz

Thank you for help.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, to make the video have the same margin on each side as the content below it, give it a max-width of 100% so it doesn't go off the screen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the code to your question. Else it'll provide little benefit to future visitors. Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I hope you were able to solve your issue, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted - it will help people seeing the good answer on the page !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this css

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.responsive {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

this will remove your horizontal scroll as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is works ! But I want video banner to scroll up :D

Comment: you want banner section to scroll horizontally or vertically?

Comment: "video"banner - same as the top menu

Comment: The answer of @jminguely using the `width: calc(100% / 3);` is far better.

Answer (score 2):

If you give to your `.responsive` class the width property of `33.33%` (instead of `33%`) the right white space you mentioned should reduce.

You'll minimize the right margin to 0.01% instead of 1% (of the total width).

There is also the option to use the css calc operator: `width: calc(100% / 3);`

Comment: Thank you- 33,33% I already tried, but gallery is not responsive to that (third picture just went above first two) -  calc(100% / 3); working(!), but still, its not same as the video banner :/ it bothers me, thanks to top banner, when you slide, you can see it (code was change for calc(100% / 3);).

Comment: Because the element in the banner is currently way larger than your viewport, it is currently overflowing on the right. As Paige mentioned in her response you should add a `max-width: 100%` to the video element to make it fit the window width.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have several issues there.

First: you don't need to use Arial font since it's a system font!

Second: You need to set the width of your video tag to max-width: 100%.

Third: the nav bar don't need to be margin-top: -75px. You should fix other margins instead!

Fourth: use an external css file instead.

Fifth: use your browser dev tools to help you figure out issues with your site, usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (WIN) <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (OSX) ([Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW1) )

Comment: Thank for help, Iam newbie in coding and this is my first big one. 1. ok 2. ok 3. I improvised 4. I will in the end - but in this way, you can see it. 5. Where is Opt ? :P

Comment: jminguely: Alt Key is the Option Key ;)
Mr 537h: the Opt/Alt Key solution is for a mac user ;)